# PHP - Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am relatively new to PHP. I am trying to display a XML response from a restful Web Service. Below is my code snippet:

```
<?php
      if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

        $name = $_GET['company'];

        $url = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/xml?input=$name";
        $client = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($client);
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
        curl_close($client);

        foreach($xml->LookupResultList as $oEntry){
          echo $oEntry->LookupResultList->LookupResult[i]->symbol . "\n";
        }
      }
    ?>
```

I get the following error in the console:

```
Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
```

Also $xml is blank.

Comment: Check what your `$response` is.

Comment: Then you should check if `$xml` is blank and only process if it's not

Comment: @MehulMohan response has the xml tags and values

Comment: Can you provide real xml response (or real URL)?

Comment: @fusion3k http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/xml?input=APPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach` loop you have to use directly `<LookupResult>` tag, and inside the loop you don't have to call the complete three, but only the `<LookupResult>` child(ren):

```
foreach( $xml->LookupResult as $oEntry )
{
    echo $oEntry->Symbol . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Also, I don't know what do you exactly mean with “$xml is blank”; BTW, to print out XML from `SimpleXML` you can use this syntax:

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```